# Bootstrap Menu Bar Active Tab

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been having trouble getting a bootstrap menu bar to display an active tab.  I used http://bootstrapdesigntools.com/tools/bootstrap-menu-builder/ to create my menubar and on the website it displays an active tab.  However, on my site it's not working.  How would I add an active tab?

I tried:

```
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .active{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Logo</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/products">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(47, 196, 116, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(47, 196, 116, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(47, 196, 116, 1) 100%);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(68, 229, 74, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(66, 165, 3, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(66, 165, 3, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(66, 165, 3, 1) 100%);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #42a503;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {

    background-color: #42a503;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #42a503;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #2fc474;
}
```

Comment: You're not using the `active` class anywhere. Put it on one of the `<li>` elements. Your CSS works fine. Bootstrap gives an example [here](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/). You can inspect the element to see how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also add the `.active` class to one of the `<li>` elements:

```
<li class="active">
   <a href="/products">Products</a>
</li>
```

```css
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(47, 196, 116, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(47, 196, 116, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(47, 196, 116, 1) 100%);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(68, 229, 74, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(66, 165, 3, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(66, 165, 3, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(66, 165, 3, 1) 100%);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #42a503;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {

    background-color: #42a503;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #42a503;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #2fc474;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Logo</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active"><a href="/products">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple.  Thank you.  Marked your answer as correct because it was the most thorough

Answer (score 1):

put `active` in one of the `<li>` you want . Hope this help

Comment: Got it!  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
<div class="active">
<!–– YOUR CODE --!>
</div>
```

That should work. Hope it helps

Comment: Recheck the HTML comment sysntax.